# std::chrono::from_stream gcc availability, is unavailable in gcc 10.1.0

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I'm wondering what version of gcc I need to use new [`std::chrono::from_stream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/from_stream). I'm on `10.1.0` but the compiler doesn't know the name. I don't see any trace of the feature on the [GNU cxx status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html). Thank you!

```
#include <chrono>
std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeDuration);


 error: no member named 'from_stream' in namespace 'std::chrono' [clang-diagnostic-error]
     std::chrono::from_stream(stream, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeDuration);


# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 10.1.0
```

Comment: It's part of the standard library. You need to look at what features the standard library supplies. I'm guessing they haven't gotten around to this.

Comment: Looks like only partial support is offered currently.  See the listing for P0355 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Comment: That's a groovy link, @NathanOliver . I usually wind up [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), but yours is a lot easier to browse.

Answer (score 3):

[Your link](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) is for the C++ compiler status.  [Here is the status of the gcc std::lib](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020).  As I write this, it isn't implemented yet (though I'm aware work has begun).

Until it is available, [here is a free, open-source preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  `from_stream` (and `parse`) are in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`, and in the header `date.h`.